# bash countdown(up?) timer w/alarm: improvements?

Tags: bash, timer, terminal, beep

`MIN=1 && for i in $(seq $(($MIN*5)) -1 1); do echo -n "$i, "; sleep 60; done; while :; do beep -r 25 -l 3; sleep 5; done`

I decided recently to experiment with the [pomodoro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) work/learning technique and, since I am usually working with a computer, wanted to be able to cobble together a countdown/up timer with alarm that runs on the machine at which I'm working. In brief, I wanted to count down/up either a 25 minute or 5 minute interval, by minute, then have an alarm sound--an alarm that will sound until reset. I wanted this, by the way, to be a non-gui solution that I can run from a terminal

Searching the web, I came up with something that works (mostly taken from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5886/countdown-clock )--see above. It counts down and displays time remaining by minutes and, when the specified interval ends, it plays a distinctive but fairly non-intrusive system bell pattern (uses the "beep" program) every 5 seconds until <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is entered in the terminal from which the script was run.

As I said, what I have put together seems like it will suit my needs adequately. But since my understanding of bash is quite limited--as, by looking at the script, should be evident to anyone with bash-scripting experience--I thought I would ask here what sorts of improvements might be made to this script? Can it be further condensed, and/or perhaps use different utilities to achieve the same end, but in a more elegant manner? Input will be appreciated.

LATER EDIT: Zoltan's suggestion of replacing `MIN=1 && for i in $(seq $(($MIN*5)) -1 1);` with `for i in $(seq 5 -1 1);` does, it seems to me, somewhat simplify and improve the script I posted. So a more sensible version of this as a one-liner would be `for i in $(seq 5 -1 1); do echo -n "$i, "; sleep 60; done; while :; do beep -r 25 -l 3; printf " # "; sleep 5; done`. The version he posted does seem a far more capable and flexible script, so I will mark it as the best answer. Although it's good to have an option like that available, I think I'll go ahead and stick with the version I created (including the slight improvement suggested by Zoltan and one I thought up that adds a hash sign each time the beep goes off [to give me an idea, in case I should leave the computer, how long it's been beeping]--the `printf " # "` part) that has the time interval hard-coded into the script. Thanks for the input.

Comment: your good question can be improved if you put the second code in a separate block - and with comments - so that the whole post is more readable. Although it is `bash`
, I prefer line separation as in  the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40096676/1705829)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your script is fair enough.

I don't really see the point in the && at

```
MIN=1 && for
```

it means, if the first term is successful, only then execute the second term. I am not even sure, what is the logical value of an assignment, but it is is safe to assume, it is successful. So a

```
MIN=1; for ...
```

should suffice.

As for this 2-liner, the whole MIN=1 seems pointless, You could just write

```
for i in $(seq 5 -1 1); do ...
```

On the other hand, You might want to be able to change the alloted time, which can be achieved like this:

1) create a file like beeper.sh

2) make it executable by your user

```
chmod u+x beeper.sh
```

or by all user:

```
chmod a+x beeper.sh
```

3) write your script in the file, with a little tweak:

```
#!/bin/bash

# default timeout
timeout_mins=5
# while testing your script, making changes, you want this to be something like 1 or 2
sec_per_min=60

# check for command line input
if [ 0 -ne $# ]
then
    # assign the first command line param, no check, if it is a number, though!
    timeout_mins=$1
fi

# now it does make sense, to have a variable in the for loop core
for i in $(seq $timeout_mins -1 1)
do
    echo -n "$i, "
    sleep $sec_per_min
done

while :
do
    beep -r 25 -l 3
    sleep 5
done
```

4) execute your script like this (from the dir the script file is in):

```
# using the default time
./beeper.sh

# using 9min
./beeper.sh 9

# invalid input: the seq will fail -> the for will fail -> execute the beep
./beeper.sh bla
```

Comment: I tried this script and it does function along the lines I'd envisioned. It is much more flexible and capable than what I originally posted. So I will mark this solution as the best answer, though I will likely be continuing to use a slightly-modified version of the script I posted initially.

Comment: Can you explain `beep` cause I did not find info in `man` about `r` and `l` flags. Maybe left and right speaker? With `seq` I got `first`, `incr` and `last`
 as flags from `man`.

Comment: @Timo beep -h: -r REPS, -l LENGTH_ms

Answer (score 0):

You can do infinite loop within you will just call beep I think you dont need that for cycle you can sleep for some time beep then get back to that state and run it on subshell

```
#infinite loop with beep man beep to understand better -r and -l switch
time=$((60*5))
current=0
while :
do
 #echo "Current time is: "
 #date  | egrep -o [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+

  current=$(($current+$time / 60))
  echo "time of execution : $current min";
  beep -r 25 -l 10
  sleep $time
done
```

I am not sure if i got understand well your problem but solution depends only on you if you want a timer that counts every minute then solution cannot be easier than that wihch you posted ABOVE.

Comment: This looks a lot like my original rendtiion--sleep 5m && while :; do beep -r 25 -l 10; sleep 5; done . That counts to 5 minutes--making no sound--then, when the 5 minutes is up, plays the specified beep command every 5 seconds until the command is manually ended (by ctrl c). I wanted to enhance that version by adding a visible timer that would show, roughly where within the 5 minute interval, the running countdown was currently positioned. The script I found allowed me to add the enhancement (numerical countdown) I was looking for. I hope my aim is a little clearer now.

Comment: i edited script above you can check it but another answer is there so choose better solution :)